# Recurrence while executing script multiple times in terminal

Tags: terminal, julia, mathematical-optimization

I'm trying to implement the gradient descent optimization method in julia, and while it produces the results i'm looking for when executing the first time, if i repeat the code it begins to change the results until it's all NaN. I'm assuming one or more of the variables carry the value to the next execution but i can't find out which one is doing this.

I'm not very used to programming, having very little experience with atual algorithms, so please excuse the poor coding and, if possible, advise on how to make it better.

Here's my code:

```
using LinearAlgebra #pacote de álgebra linear

# Parâmetros importantes do método do gradiente 
h = 0.001 #passo da derivada numérica
precision_a = 1.0e-04 #precisão da função de otimização de alfa
precision_fun = 1.0e-08 #precisão da função gradiente
a0 = 0.0 #chute inicial de alfa

#parâmetros de entrada
f1_jac(x1::Float64,x2::Float64) = 1 + 4x1 +2x2
f2_jac(x1::Float64,x2::Float64) = -1 + 2x1 +2x2
jac = [f1_jac,f2_jac]
n = length(jac)
x0 = [0.0,0.0]

#variáveis auxiliares
grad_a = zeros(n) 
grad_xk = zeros(n)
grad_xk1 = zeros(n)

function f_a(a::Float64,x::Array)
    for i=1:n
        grad_a[i] = jac[i](x...)
    end
    xk1 = x - a.*grad_a
    for i=1:n
        grad_xk1[i] = jac[i](xk1...)
    end
    return transpose(grad_a)*grad_xk1
end

function df_a(a::Float64,x::Array)
    df_a = (f_a(a+h,x)-f_a(a-h,x))/2h
    return df_a
end

function teste(x::Array)
    xa = x
    k_alfa = 0
    a_k = 0
    a_dummy = a0
    erro_a = 1.0
    while erro_a>precision_a && k_alfa<=1000
        k_alfa += 1
        a_k = a_dummy - f_a(a_dummy,xa)/df_a(a_dummy,xa)
        erro_a = abs(a_k-a_dummy)
    end
    return a_k
end

function teste2()
    k_it = 0
    x_dummy = x0 
    erro_fun = 1.0
    x_k = zeros(n)
    while erro_fun>precision_fun && k_it<=1000
        alfa = teste(x_dummy)
        x_k = x_dummy - alfa.*grad_a
        erro_fun = max(abs.(grad_a)...)
        x_dummy .= x_k
        k_it+=1
        println("$k_it = iteração e $(trunc(alfa,digits = 2)) = alfa")
    end
    return trunc.(x_k,digits=2)
end
```

The "correct answer" should be x = [-1.0,1.5] and alfa = 1.0. It results in this answer in the first run, but if i run the script again it begins to change.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your intuition is correct. The problem is the line `x_dummy = x0` in the function `teste2`. Assigning `Arrays` in this way results in `x_dummy` and `x0` referring to the same underlying chunk of memory: any changes that you make in `x_dummy` are also changes that you make in `x0`. This is a common tripping point for new programmers. You want to create an explicit copy instead.

`x_dummy = copy(x0)`.

Consider as an example.

```
julia> x0 = zeros(5)
5-element Vector{Float64}:
 0.0
 0.0
 0.0
 0.0
 0.0

julia> x_dummy = x0
5-element Vector{Float64}:
 0.0
 0.0
 0.0
 0.0
 0.0

julia> x_dummy .= 1
5-element Vector{Float64}:
 1.0
 1.0
 1.0
 1.0
 1.0

julia> x0
5-element Vector{Float64}:
 1.0
 1.0
 1.0
 1.0
 1.0
```